From a list containing letters and numbers, how do I create a list of the positions of strings that fit a parameter?
I have a list created from a list(input()), that contains letter and numbers,
like ['F', 'G', 'H', '1', '5', 'H']
I don't know the contents of the list before hand.
How would I create a new list that shows the positions of strings that fit a predefined parameter so that I could receive an output like number_list = [3, 4] and letter_list = [0, 1, 2, 5]?
I think my answer might involve index, enumerate(), and a for loop but I'm not sure how to go about filtering list contents in the way I want.
I want the positional values of the strings in the list so I can use min() and max() functions so that the leftmost letter cant appear after the rightmost number. And later prevent the first number being used from being a 0.

There's no need to convert the input into a list. You can loop over a string just like a list.

It’s fairly unclear what you mean.  OK, I get the two sample outputs.  But what do you mean by “predefined parameter”?   enumerate, yes, makes sense.  But min and max are irrelevant here.  Is there something else implied in your problem?   Why not give an actual example of your predefined parameter?   Yes, you could write a function that takes an input data list and a tuple of predicate functions ( like isnumeric, isalpha )  that returns tuples of position lists.   But the result wouldn't have your convenient names.

You can use a simple for loop with isdigit():
def _collect(L):
    nums, alphas = [], []
    for i, val in enumerate(L):
        if val.isdigit():
            nums.append(i)
        else:
            alphas.append(i)
    return nums, alphas


print(_collect(['F', 'G', 'H', '1', '5', 'H']))

Prints
([3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 5])


Just another take - this time using sets...
myList = ['F', 'G', 'H', '1', '5', 'H']

theNumbers = [pos for pos in range(len(myList)) if myList[pos].isdigit()]

theOthers = sorted(list(set(range(len(myList))) - set(theNumbers) ))

print("numbers:", theNumbers )
print(" others:", theOthers )

Output:
numbers: [3, 4]
 others: [0, 1, 2, 5]


You can use list comprehensions with built-in functions isdigit() and isalpha():
li = ['F', 'G', 'H', '1', '5', 'H']

numb_l = [i for i in range(len(li)) if li[i].isdigit()]
print("Number positions:", numb_l)
char_l = [i for i in range(len(li)) if li[i].isalpha()]
print("Character positions:", char_l)

Output:
Number positions: [3, 4]
Character positions: [0, 1, 2, 5]

